# How to get the URL of Swarm agent load balancer in Azure container service

Tags: azure, docker, docker-swarm

I'm a new user of Azure. I tried the [demo](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/container-service-docker-swarm/) of Docker Swarm in Azure Container Service, but when I deploy a new container in the Docker Swarm, I find I can't get the URL to visit the website.

> You can now access the application that is running in this container through the public DNS name of the Swarm agent load balancer. You can find this information in the Azure portal:

But I couldn't find it in my Azure, where can I get this URL?

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal, select the container service's resource group, then select the item prefixed with `swarm-agent-ip`. The DNS name for the IP address is one of the properties on the Overview tab.